# Unable to insert datetime value into a MySQL table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to run the following code in PHP:

```
<?php
require_once 'Admin/Connector.php';

$name = 'A Schandillia';
$number = '12345678910';
$latitude = '73.897687';
$longitude = '11.958271';
$sql = 'INSERT INTO distilled_contacts (PHONE, POPULARNAME, PREFERREDNAME, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, LASTSEEN) VALUES ';
$sql .= '(:num, :name, :name, :lat, :lon:, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE PREFERREDNAME = :name, LATITUDE = COALESCE(:lat, LATITUDE), LONGITUDE = COALESCE(:lon, LONGITUDE);';

$connect = dbconn(PROJHOST,PROJDB,PROJDBUSER,PROJDBPWD);

$query = $connect->prepare($sql);

$query->bindParam(':num', $number);
$query->bindParam(':name', $name);
$query->bindParam(':lat', $latitude);
$query->bindParam(':lon', $longitude);

$query->execute();

?>
```

However, it refuses to recognize CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and throws this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':, "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE PREFERREDNAME = 'A Schandillia',' at line 1' in /Users/Amit/Sites/project/test.php:24 Stack trace: #0 /Users/Amit/Sites/project/test.php(24): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /Users/Amit/Sites/project/test.php on line 24
```

I have even tried replacing it with NOW() but the problem persists. Is there no way to programmatically enter datetime value into a MySQL table?

P.S. Please don't suggest using **timestamp** data type instead of **datetime** on my table because that will not work in my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The error is very explicit: you have an error in your SQL syntax. The error goes even into details: the wrong syntax is located at ":" character preceding `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Now look closely at your query:

```
                              ↴
:num, :name, :name, :lat, :lon:
```

What do you see at the right of `lon`? Is it somehow different from `lat` or `name`?